# can not correctly insert text into a bookmark from another bookmark

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

I'm writing a windows form application which must exchange the content of Word bookmarks between two documents.

There are two similar documents *(wordDocument and wordPattern)* with similar amount of bookmarks. I'm trying this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= wordDocument.Bookmarks.Count; i++)
{
     object j = i;

     wordDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref j).Range.Text = wordPattern.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref j).Range.Text.ToString();
     //MessageBox.Show(wordDocument.Bookmarks[i].Range.Text);
     //MessageBox.Show(wordPattern.Bookmarks[i].Range.Text);
}
```

But it does the task incorrectly. I mean, it does it in improper order and deletes bookmarks. Help me by providing right way to exchange the text inside the bookmarks.

Comment: "Assign the newText string to the Range.Text property of the bookmark, which automatically deletes the bookmark. Then re-add the bookmark to the Bookmarks collection", see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad6ks7k0.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                 int count1 = 0;
                 int count2 = 0;

                 foreach (Word.Bookmark bookmark1 in wordDocument.Bookmarks)
                 {
                      Word.Range bmRange = bookmark1.Range;
                      //bmRange.Text = "заметка" + count1;
                      listOfRanges.Add(bmRange);
                      count1++; 
                 }

                 foreach (Word.Bookmark bookmark2 in wordPattern.Bookmarks)
                 {
                      Word.Range mbRange = bookmark2.Range;
                      mbRange.Text = listOfRanges[count2].Text;
                      count2++;
                 }
```

Solved it that way.